# Rails I18n with serialized attributes using fields_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization

Consider this setup:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User > ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :login, :options
  serialize :options, OpenStruct
end

#app/views/users/_form.html.erb
form_for @user do |f|
  f.label :login
  f.fields_for :options, @user.options do |options|
    options.label :emailme
  end
end 

#config/locals/en.yml
  en:
    activerecord:
      attributes:
        user: 
          login: "User Name"
          options: 
            emailme: "Email Preference"
```

The problem I'm trying to solve is being able to localize the label tag for an attribute(:emailme) of the serialized attribute "options".

I've dug deep into the rails source and figured out that the problem is because when I call options.label its expects there to be an object, but there is no object because the object name that is passed down is "user[options"] and that is not a valid instance variable name.

See [line 1124 of form_helper.rb on rails github](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb#L1124) where it retrieves the object.  There is a comment that even mentions to fallback to nil when object_name is item[subobject].

And so, when it goes to create the actual label [Line 1110 form_helper.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb#L1110) it defaults to method_name.humanize

Is there any decent way to accomplish localization with serialized attributes?

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, I discovered I could use i18n helpers like so(and not have to change anything in the form):

```
 en:
   helpers:
   label:
    "user[options]":
       emailme: "Email Preference"
```

Although this still doesn't cover validation messages...

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to create your own keys and explicitly call I18n.translate ?

see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html

```
# config/locals/en.yml
en:
  users:
    email_preference: "Email Preference"

# app/views/users/_form.html.erb
form_for @user do |f|
  f.label :login
  f.fields_for :options, @user.options do |options|
    options.label :emailme, I18n.translate('users.email_preference')
  end
end
```

Warning: untested code

might also work using your existing config? `I18n.translate('activerecord.attributes.user.options.emailme')`

also you can 'scope' your keys in the locals file to actions and controllers

Comment: this would indeed work, but I was looking for more of a framework-based solution.  It always irks me when framework behavior isn't consistent, and particularly with ruby on rails because its otherwise ridiculously flexible and extensible.  The advantage of specifying it in the attributes scope is that validate error messages will get this translation.  So to make your solution fully work right, I'd have to specify essentially the same thing in two places...not very d.r.y.